# "Avoided" categorized as a type of presupposition

Tags: pragmatics

while reading [a Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presupposition) about pragmatics and presuppositions, I came upon this explanation:

> Some further implicative predicates: [...] X avoided Ving » X was expected to, or usually did, or
> ought to V, etc.

I don't understand how it presupposes the implication of "usually did".

If one says: "Tom avoided gaining weight." I could understand it presupposes Tom should have gained weight, ie. expected to gain weights. Yet, it seems to be a stretch to presuppose Tom usually gained weight.

Would someone please help explain? Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: The presupposition is that there was something to be avoided (and then it was avoided). *John avoided locking the door. John was expected to lock the door, but he avoided doing so. John usually locks the door, but this time he avoided it.*

Comment: It's not only something that he's expected to do, it can be something he is in danger of doing. For instance "Fred avoided Covid-19  by  social distancing".